# Filtering rows that are dependent on other rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table in Excel:

```
id  color   variance
1   Red     50.6
2   Blue    65.3
3   Red     55.3
4   Violet  40.6
5   Purple  40.2
6   Red     33.3
7   Red     27.5
8   Blue    43.3
9   Orange  23.3
10  Blue    12.1
```

I want to filter and show the rows whose variance matches another variance + 10. That is, after applying the filter, I will be having these results.

```
id  color   variance
1   Red     50.6 
2   Blue    65.3
3   Red     55.3 
4   Violet  40.6        
6   Red     33.3        
8   Blue    43.3
9   Orange  23.3
```

I tried using the `advanced` filtering, of no avail.
I know this can be done easily using a macro, but I do not want to use macros.

Comment: Do you just want to remove anything past id 10? Or is there more to it?

Comment: The table is around 60,000 values. @PhilK

Comment: So what are you trying to filter out? Do you just want the top 10 ids?

Comment: @PhilK I want to filter and show the rows whose variance matches another variance + 10.

Comment: So in relation to the top example, purple had a variance of 40.2 and violet had a variance of 40.6 so the match is 40? And you want to remove one of the duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `id` in A1 I think you could differentiate those to keep from those to delete (or show/not show) with, in D2 and copied down to suit:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,C2+10)+COUNTIF(C:C,C2-10)
```

Comment: What does this do? I tried it, it does not work. It shows numbers in the D column.